# How to get the dynamically column index while clicking on a cell using wpf GridControl DevExpress?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a problem related with the DevExpress GridControl when I click on any GridControl cell then it will return the clicked column Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify clicked [column](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridViewInfoGridHitInfo_Columntopic) and this column [visible index](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_VisibleIndextopic) using the hit-information returned by the [GridView.CalcHitInfo()](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CalcHitInfotopic) method:

```
GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
if(hitInfo.InRowCell){
    int columnIndex = hitInfo.Column.VisibleIndex;
    //...
}
```

Related help-article: [Hit Information Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument770)
Related How-To: [Identify the Grid's Element Located Under the Mouse Cursor](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3052)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how a Windows Forms answer about DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView is a correct answer to a question about the WPF control DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl, which very definitely does not have a method called CalcHitInfo. But it's none of my business, I suppose.